# How to read XLSB files from C# - Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook

Tags: c#, .net, excel, office-interop

I'm getting error while trying to open XLSB file using Interop, please help me to resolve the issue. I need to use Interop for sure.

Error Message :

> "Excel cannot open the file 'Results_Preprod.xlsb' because the file
>   format or file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not
>   been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the
>   file."

Code :

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application(); 
//Issue Line :
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(excelFilePath,
                        0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows,
                        "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
```

Give me a sample is possible